# more concise jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm sure this is an easy question but I'll ask anyway.
How do I make this into more concise code:

```
        $(window).scroll(function () { ScrollTheDivs(); })
        $(window).resize(function () { ScrollTheDivs(); })
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(window).bind('scroll resize', ScrollTheDivs);
```